# ios physical device cannot to localhost on window machine

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, localhost, vmware

So I'm running Mac OS on windows using VMWare to build ios apps.
Right now I have an iPad that I'm using to connect to the localhost, that is on a windows machine. I came across a similar post but it was never answered and can't find it again.
So, I added a UKWebView to see if it is connecting to the HTML and PHP file that I have rooted in c:/apache/htdoc/index.html

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let urlString = "http://192.xxx.xx.x/intialize.php"
    let getUrl = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!)
    self.web.load(getUrl)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //employees.downloadItems()

}
```

on the simulator, it works fine but on a physical device nothing.
Something I have come across to resolve my problem on StackOverflow.

ios device and localhost using the same IP address,

in httpd.conf change Listen to the IP address #Listen 192.xxx.xx.x:80,

add the computers name (since I'm using a window)

```
let urlString = "http://computersName/192.xxx.xx.x/intialize.php"
```

also, I did add this to info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

still no luck. Am I missing something?

Comment: `localhost` is whatever device your app is running on.

Comment: check if you can open `http://192.xxx.xx.x/intialize.php` in safari

Comment: @bazyl87 on the simulator I can, but not on my iPad.

Comment: Again, `localhost` is the device your app is running on. When you run your app on your iPad, `localhost` is the iPad. But your server is not running on the iPad.

Comment: @rmaddy ahhh.....ok. Had to google a little more and found this https://wesbos.com/localhost-mobile-device-testing/
that goes into depth about what you pointed out.

Comment: if anyone ever runs into the same issue as I did.
tip 1: allow port through firewall
tip 2: granting access for other devices to get stuff on Apache 2.4 httpd.conf